# What are the consequences of having (too) many namespaces?

Tags: c#, namespaces, code-analysis

I run code analysis on a project and I get a warning saying

**CA1020 : Microsoft.Design : Consider merging the types defined in {some namespace} with another namespace.    {some namespace}**

Why do I get this? Is there a negative implication of having too many namespaces?

Comment: My problem with this warning is that code analysis is not taking into consideration that I have 20 other Visual Studio solutions that are also creating classes in the same namespace. So for me it's usually a "false positive", and I've simply suppressed it ny my custom rule set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the main reason is discoverability and believe that plays a large part in the successful support and maintenance of your code. If it's easier to discover it *should* be easier to maintain.

Here's the a quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182130.aspx).

> Namespaces should
>   contain types that are used together
>   in most scenarios. When their
>   applications are mutually exclusive,
>   types should be located in separate
>   namespaces. Careful namespace
>   organization can also be helpful
>   because it increases the
>   discoverability of a feature. By
>   examining the namespace hierarchy,
>   library consumers should be able to
>   locate the types that implement a
>   feature

Answer (score 1):

There are no real negative implications at runtime, in terms of increased memory or execution times.  Also, namespaces are not like IP addresses, which have a fixed pool and can eventually run out.

Namespaces are basically a naming convention to help you group related things together.  The CA error is suggesting that too many small namespaces may make your code harder for other people to use.